# Returning only the last value of query

Tags: php, html

This is my second code but the problem is I have 3 queries. So it only returns the last product_id when i Click update it always return product_id=3, but i want update the product_id=2

```
<form action="update_qty.php" method="POST">
<?php while($getorder = mysqli_fetch_array($order)){ ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$getorder['price']?>" name="actual_price">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$getorder['product_id']?>" name="product">
    <input type="text" value="<?=$getorder['qty']?>" name="qty" size="1" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="submit" value="update" name="update">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't think you can do it this way. GET Values can either be passed using URL or  a form tag using method="GET" (in which case POST is probably better anyway). You might be better off using AJAX/jQuery if you don't want an explicit form/submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more information like this

```
<a href="update_qty.php?product_id=<?=$getorder['product_id']?>&type=text">update</a>
```

Comment: No, I added '&type=text'

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the PHP is server side and you need something client side to read the value of the text box. You would need a page refresh to pass the text field value to the server so it could write it to the url in the anchor tag. Which is what the form submit would do, but as it would have submitted the value already the anchor tag would be pointless

To do it without a page refresh use Javascript. It would be easy to do with jQuery. You could add an event that writes whatever is entered in the text box the the anchor tags href as it is typed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="update_qty.php?product_id=<?php echo $getorder['product_id']?>">update</a>
```

On `update_qty.php` u can use like this

```
<?php echo $_GET['product_id'];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something more like this.
One form per product.In your case when you submit the form the qty value will always be the las found.

```
<?php while($getorder = mysqli_fetch_array($order)){ ?>
    <form action="update_qty.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$getorder['price']?>" name="actual_price">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$getorder['product_id']?>" name="product">
        <input type="text" value="<?=$getorder['qty']?>" name="qty" size="1" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" value="update" name="update">
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not get all values as like that because input name overwrite in every loop iteration.

For multiple values you can try in two ways like:

```
<?php 
while($getorder = mysqli_fetch_array($order)){ 
$newArr[] = $getorder['price']."~".$getorder['product_id']."~". $ getorder['qty'];
} //while end
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="allinputs" value="<?=$newArr?>">
```

Input field outside the loop.

In php explode array value with ~ and get the all values.

Other solution is that
Your input field name must be change like:

```
<?php while($getorder = mysqli_fetch_array($order)){ ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$getorder['price']?>" name="actual_price_<?=$getorder['product_id']?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Change field name in every iteration.

In current scenario either you need three different buttons or the best solution to use AJAX request .